# Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, lamp, php7

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 wanted to install LAMP Stack via below commands,

```
    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge php5-*
    sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get -y install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-dev
   sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.1
   sudo apt-get -y install php7.1-pgsql php7.1-mysql
   sudo apt-get -y install php7.1-fpm php7.1-bz2 php7.1-json php7.1-phpdbg php7.1-intl php7.1-gd php7.1-curl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-xdebug php7.1-xml php7.1-zip
  sudo apt-get -y install php-pear php-imagick php7.1-imap php-memcache php7.1-pspell php7.1-recode php7.1-sqlite3 php7.1-tidy php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-xsl php-gettext
```

Apache2 and php is working More on running `php composer.phar install` got below errors

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'readline' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'recode' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tidy' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'readline' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'recode' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tidy' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                        
  Unable to parse file "/var/www/html/symfony2-demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml".  

  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                             
  The XML file "/var/www/html/symfony2-demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml" is not valid.  

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement  
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                  
  Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded                                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                        
  PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                        
  PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                              
  PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                        
  PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                          
  PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                        
  PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                          
  PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                      
  PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                          
  PHP Warning:  Module 'readline' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                        
  PHP Warning:  Module 'recode' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                          
  PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                           
  PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                         
  PHP Warning:  Module 'tidy' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                            
  PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                          
  PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                       
  PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             
  PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0                                                                             

    [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                               
    Unable to parse file "/var/www/html/symfony2-demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml".                                                                                                    
    [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                               
    The XML file "/var/www/html/symfony2-demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml" is not valid.                                                                                              
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                           
    Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem connected with this feature of composer https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/issues/58

You may disable xdebug to make things works.